# Synaptics Touchpad Scrolling not working

Tags: touchpad, synaptics

After upgrading Ubuntu 14.04 -> 14.10 -> 15.04, the Synaptics Touchpad no longer works properly.  In 14.04 it was fine, in 14.10 it did not work at all, but in 15.04 it works minimally in that I can do everything except scroll.

The Ubuntu help page says:

> **Basic Configuration with a Graphical Interface**
>
> Ubuntu provides basic configuration of your touchpad options in System -> Preferences -> Mouse, under the Touchpad tab.
>
> Try the touchpad after unchecking the Enable mouse clicks with
>   touchpad check box.
>
> Check operation after Enable horizontal scrolling is checked. This may
>   not have been the default setting.

---

However, when I open the system configuration tool and select, "Mouse and Touchpad" (I assume that is what System -> Preferences -> Touchpad is referring to), these options don't exist.

If I try to use synclient, I get:

"Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?"

Is there anything I can do to get scrolling working?

Thanks

Peter

Comment: Search for `Additional Drivers` in Unity Dash and see if mousepad drivers are available.

Comment: A search for "additional drivers" in the dash return nothing.  Do I need to install something?

Comment: Ah!!  But a search for 'controladores aditionales' returns something :-/  It shows the driver for the wireless card, an unspecified non-functioning device, and nothing else.

Comment: You might just have to wait for an update.

Comment: I may be waiting a long time, then, given that it didn't work at all in 14.10.  The thing I can't figure is that it worked just fine in 14.04.  Is there anyone I should inform about it?  Report a bug or something?

Comment: This fixes it for a single session:   

`peter@peter-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo rmmod psmouse  
peter@peter-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo modprobe -v  psmouse  
insmod /lib/modules/3.16.0-34-generic/kernel/drivers/input/mouse/psmouse.ko   
peter@peter-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC:~$ `  

Can't find any way of making it permanent, though.

Comment: You can make those scripts and then tell Ubuntu to run those scripts upon login. Make a text file, put `#!/bin/bash` at the top, then put every command you ran on separate lines below that.

Comment: How can I get the script to run as root?  If I can't do that it will either fail, or prompt for the password.  Either way, it doesn't provide any advantage, really.

Comment: Tried putting the commands in a startup script (psmouse.conf) in /etc/init but it didn't work.

Comment: I think if you tell them to run at startup, using System Settings, they should run as root.

Comment: I had it running as root by putting the script in /etc/init, but it didn't work.

Comment: As the admin is getting annoyed, I'll start a new query.

Comment: There is an application that comes with Ubuntu that lets you specify programs or scripts to run at startup. You need to do this.

Comment: Yeah.  Tried all those.  Didn't work.  Using rc.local turned out to be the solution in the end.

Comment: Well, glad it's been worked around.

Comment: I have the same problem with a Lenovo Yoga Pro 2.