# Help applying touchpad fix to rc.local

Tags: drivers, kernel, mouse, touchpad

I'm new to Ubuntu and trying to implement a permanent solution to my `touchpad` not working in Ubuntu 15.04. The solution I have so far only works until I restart/reboot so I've tried to add it to `rc.local`. The short term fix is to use the following lines in the terminal:

```
sudo rmmod psmouse
sudo modprobe -v psmouse insmod /lib/modules/3.16.0-34-generic/kernel/drivers/input/mouse/psmouse.ko
```

my `rc.local` document now reads:

```
!/bin/sh -e

chmod u+x /home/nurho@NuRho/modprobe -v psmouse insmod /lib/modules/3.16.0-34-generic/kernel/drivers/input/mouse/psmouse.ko
exit 0
```

the above is what I've pieced together (unsuccessfully) through looking at other posts concerning this sort of thing. Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks.

(thanks to pl_rock for tidying up the question)

Comment: It looks like you do everything wrong. What is your touchpad, where did you get that module? And modules are added not in `rc.local`. And the line there is all wrong.

Comment: I suspected I was way-off @Pilot6. I found the short-term fix here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/615042/synaptics-touchpad-scrolling-not-working. It works for me too. The op states in one of the last comments that he applied it to rc.local and it created a permanent fix. I read elsewhere that chmod u+x was neccissary to make the command executable and elsewhere that /home/username/ needed to come before the command for it to work. It's a synaptics touchpad on a lenova ideapad yoga 11s. Is there any more info I could give that would be helpful to sorting this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the permanent fix will be

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

And the correct command in rc.local will be

```
rmmod psmouse
modprobe -v psmouse insmod /lib/modules/3.16.0-34-generic/kernel/drivers/input/mouse/psmouse.ko
```

without all those wrong things like `chmod u+x /home/nurho@NuRho/`.

But it is still not a correct way.

Comment: Thanks for this. Where would I type that? I tried it in terminal and I now have a cursor on screen where previously there was nothing, but there is no movement for it.

Comment: It is to be run in terminal. But it may take a few seconds to be done.

Comment: Great. I tried it again but I still can't move the cursor. It does, however, appear wherever I touch the touch-screen.

Comment: I think it is better to remove all you installed before and ask a new question regarding how to get your touchpad working.

Comment: Did you download and install some `psmouse.ko`?

Comment: I did download and install psmouse.ko but it only worked as part of the temp fix. I'll ask a new question about getting the touchpad working - thanks for your help with this.