# Synaptics touchpad not responding

Tags: touchpad, synaptics

I'm not so much new to Linux, but I've never really messed around with it much so I can't troubleshoot any issues. I got a HP Pavilion Dv6 with a Synaptics touchpad. I've had ubuntu on this before with no issues. I had to reinstall after a hard drive crashed, I replaced it with an OEM drive and reinstalled 12.04, then upgraded up to 15.04.

I'm not sure if my track pad worked in 12.04 this time around, I was using a USB mouse while it upgraded. But all versions after that it does not work. Here's the thing that gets me. The computer WILL respond to the hard click buttons, and it WILL wake up if I touch the trackpad, but the cursor does not move. I'm using an external keyboard with a built in trackpad, and it's working just fine.

xinput list does show the trackpad as 
"SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad id=12 [slave pointer (2)]

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:** I've installed "xserver-xorg-core" and solve my problem (all of theme). It seems that when I upgraded from 14.05 to 14.10 and to 15.05 this and other packages (xorg) were not updated and remained as "xserver-xorg-core-lts-...". With this upgrade "xserver-xorg-input-synaptics" was installed which is the one that controls the mouse.

**ORIGINAL:** I have the same problem and searching the internet I found this solution. In the command line write:

$ sudo modprobe -r psmouse

$ sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps

After this you would see something like this in xinput list:
"ImPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad..."

However, I have 2 problems now: I couldn't manage to do it permanently and two-finger-scrolling doesn't to work.

There's some more information in this links:
[Synaptics Touchpad Scrolling not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/615042/synaptics-touchpad-scrolling-not-working) and [Synaptic touchpad on laptop not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/262287/synaptic-touchpad-on-laptop-not-working)

Comment: Just do `sudo modprobe psmouse` to use the synaptic driver and get two finger scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below as a workaround:
Press

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

to open a terminal window.Then type:

```
xinput
```

that will show you the id of the device e.g.

```
SYNA2B29:00 06CB:77C6                     id=10
```

then enter:

```
xinput disable 10 && xinput enable 10
```

substitute "10" with the id that your synaptic device has